# Bash copy files to sudirectories based on matching variable

Tags: bash, for-loop, copy

I have a directory with the following content:

```
/B7_001

/B7_002

B7_001_name.mat

B7_002_name.mat
```

Each subdirectory in this directory has the following structure:

```
/B7_001/results_activity/sham/task/
/B7_002/results_activity/sham/task/
```

I want to copy or move each file down the subdirectory tree of the subdirectory matching the first part of it's name.

For example copy file
     "B7_001_name.mat" in to /B7_001/results_activity/sham/task/.

I haven’t had much success with the following code, so any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
for i in B7_*
do
cp  ${i}_name.mat  /${i}/results_activity/sham/task/
done
```

Comment: Did you try `for i in B7_*/` ? Will use the directory names only, but however your code should have worked anyway, just throw extra errors for the matching B7_001_name.mat files where you only wanted matches on the directories ... ??..

Comment: Thanks, I did and one of the iterations of the code ended up copying the files to the /B7_001 but not /B7_001/results_activity/sham/task, I couldn't work out why. Now I see why the errors were being thrown up, seems really obvious, opps!

Comment: argl, my bad, "B7_001/"_name.mat is not good either, 'd have to strip the / - `cp ${i/\//}_name.mat ..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to understand the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob # play it safe when using globs

for i in B7_*_name.mat; do
    echo "i=$i"
    d=${i%_name.mat}
    echo "d=$d"
    echo mv "$i" "/$d/results_activity/sham/task"
done
```

Run as is, it's harmless and will not perform any actions; only print some stuff to your terminal.

- `for i in B7_*_name.mat`: that's a `for` loop where the variable `i` will successively take the filenames matching the glob `B7_*_name.mat`.
- with this variable, we remove the `_name.mat` part using the shell parameter expansion:

  ```
  d=${i%_name.mat}
  ```

  which means that `d` is the expansion `$i` where the *trailing* (because of `%`) `_name.mat` is removed.

Comment: For anyone using the code, don't forget to specify the source.                                           mv $i  ./$d/results_activity/sham/task

Answer (score 1):

How about using `find - while` combination like below :

```
find . -type f -print0 | while read -r -d ''  line
 do
   if [[ "$line" =~ ^\./B7_001 ]]
   then
    cp "$line" B7_001/results_activity/sham/task/
   elif [[ "$line" =~ ^\./B7_002 ]]
   then
    cp "$line" B7_002/results_activity/sham/task/
   fi
 done
```